# Selecting Predictors for an Outcome Model from a data set with Missing Values

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, missing-data, stepwise-regression

I want to create a model to predict a numeric improvement (e.g. reduction in a numeric parameter) after surgery.

For that I want to choose the best predictors from a list of about 30 patient characteristics (numeric and categorical). My problem is that in my data set of about 250 patients almost no patient is a complete case.

I tried to use a linear regression model and run a stepwise regression in R which resulted in this error:

`Error in step(lm_full, direction = "backward", scope = list(lower = lm_empty)): number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?`

If my understanding is correct, this because of missing values. I can avoid this error by using only complete cases for all 30 predictors, which leaves me with a tiny dataset of only a few observations. My cases are about 90% complete, but when filtering for all 30 predictors, this leaves me with almost no data.

I have thought of several possible ways to solve the problem of missing values, but I am unsure which is the statistically best:

- Preselecting predictors using an univariate regression. I would only include predictors above a certain R2 or below a certain P value in my stepwise regression. By using fewer predictors in the full model of my stepwise regression, I would have more complete cases.
- Using multiple imputation to fill missing values, although I am not sure how to combine this with a stepwise regression.
- I read that mixed effects models are better than linear models for missing values. However, I am not sure how to use a mixed effects model to select predictors for an outcome model.

I am stuck with googling for answers and would be very grateful for some tips!